# enabling debugging for web browser (as external tool ) in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing APPLET and I have eclipse set up to launch web browser (firefox).

I have now External tool that starts up FIREFOX and my applet.
I have a separate Remote debug option configured ok.

However, debugger needs to be launched separately. How can I combine these two to same hotkey?  Now I press ctrl+f11 to run external tool(firefox) and after that I need to click Debugger icon.

Comment: I used this for setting up debugger: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ve-dev/msg00092.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows>Preferences>General> Web Browser and add Firefox as the browser.

Next time when you launch the application, Eclipse will launch it in Firefox.